# Trigger - Create new record and update lookup field with the related record

Tags: apex, trigger, lookup, update, create-records

I have two objects which have a lookup relationship.

Object 1 - Task

Object 2 - Bonus__c

When a task is updated to 'Completed', I am creating a Bonus__c record.

How to update the lookup field on Task with Bonus__c value once the bonus record is created ?

Here's my code in the Task trigger Handler (afterUpdate)-

```
protected override void afterUpdate() {
    createBonusRecord();
}


public static void createBonusRecord () {    

List<Bonus__c> bonusToInsert = new List<Bonus__c>();
for (Task t : (List<Task>) Trigger.new) {
      if(t.Status = 'Completed') { 
         Bonus__c bonus = new Bonus__c();
         bonus.Stage__c = 'Evaluation';
         bonus.Type__c = 'Annual';
         bonus.Account__c = t.WhatId;
         bonus.Manager__c = t.OwnerId; 
         bonusToInsert.add(bonus);
      }
 }
    
 if(!bonusToInsert.isEmpty()) { 
   uow.RegisterNew(bonusToInsert);
   uow.commitWork();       
 }   
  
 // Update Bonus lookup field on Task with the newly created record ? 

}
```

Comment: What part of this isn't working for you? What have you tried and what errors are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using [fflib](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-common) here ... *(if not, my solution is only a guide)*

There are two parts to this issue

1. Updating the `Task.Bonus__c` field to the newly-created `Bonus__c`
2. Avoiding recursion in this trigger after you update the `Task` record from #1

   ```
   static Set<Id> visitedTasksAssignedBonuses = new Set<Id> ();

   ... 
   for (Task t :  Trigger.new) {
     if(!visitedTasksAssignedBonuses.contains(t.Id) && t.Status == 'Completed') { 
        Bonus__c bonus = new Bonus__c (
            Stage__c = 'Evaluation';
            Type__c = 'Annual';
            Account__c = t.WhatId;
            Manager__c = t.OwnerId; 
        );
        uow.registerNew(bonus);
        uow.registerDirty(t,Task.Bonus__c,bonus); // sets relationship field
        visitedTasksAssignedBonuses.add(t.Id);
     }
   }
   uow.commitWork();
   ```

Notes

1. You were missing the `==` in your if test
2. `fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork` is bulkified and you don't need to call the `registerXXX` methods with lists - in fact, if using [ApexMocks](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-mocks), it is simpler to do assertions on individual sobjects rather than lists as otherwise the syntax gets unwieldy and the apexmocks output when an assertion fail is harder to interpret.
3. Your `Application.UnitOfWork` value needs to be sure to have `Bonus__c` ahead of `Task` in the ordered list of SobjectTypes. This is best practice -  parents (e.g. `Bonus__c`) get DML before children (`Task`) - though in your case, `fflib_SobjectUnitOfWork` does inserts before updates.
4. The set of Ids is used to avoid recursion; there's an fflib_SobjectDomain alternative that shuts off the trigger handler for Tasks - [see this blog post for how to use](https://andyinthecloud.com/2016/04/13/disabling-trigger-events-in-apex-enterprise-patterns/)